# 3dplot scatter points via python

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I just used `numpy.loadtxt('filename', usecols=(0,))` to load a csv with the following format:

```
x,y,z
1.1,2.2,3.3
5.5,1.45,6.77
```

(There are ~1M lines). I'd like to make a scatterplot. I searched the web and found `numpy.meshgrid` and `mlab.surf` but I'm not sure what to do. Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you,Steve.Your method works.Any one has any idea about surface plotvia mlab.surf?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/), it's very powerful, and widely used, most importantly, it has good document and is easy to use.

Hope helps!

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple example from [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/scatter3d_demo.py).

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    return (vmax-vmin)*np.random.rand(n) + vmin

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
n = 100
for c, m, zl, zh in [('r', 'o', -50, -25), ('b', '^', -30, -5)]:
    xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
    ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
    zs = randrange(n, zl, zh)
    ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c=c, marker=m)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

You just need to parse your data instead of using randrange.